# how to dynamically import a node module after installing it during runtime

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I have a node script that is suppose to work as a CLI doing the following:

- Search node modules for a required module based on the CLI command entered
- If not found, use node's `exec` to run `npm install "dynamicModule"`
- after the module is installed, dynamically import it using `await import('dynamicModule')`

The code is able to discover if the module is available and install it successfully if not, however.. when trying to then import the module, Node complains it is not found. The module does end up in `node_modules` and if I re-run the code (the check now says the module IS installed) it is able to dynamically import it just fine.

Is there a way to dynamically import a node module at runtime that is ALSO installed at runtime?

Code below:

```
async getProviderPlugin(provider: string) {
    /**
     * Determine if the user has passed a provider and prompt them if not
     */
    const checkSpinner = ora(`Checking for ${provider} module...`)
    const hasPlugin = moduleIsAvailable(`${provider}-provider-plugin`)
    console.log(`plugin exists: ${hasPlugin}`)
    if (!hasPlugin) {
      this.log(`${provider} plugin does not exist, installing now`)
      const installOra = ora(`Installing ${provider} plugin`)
      const exec = require('child_process').exec
      await exec(`yalc add ${provider}-provider-plugin`)
      installOra.succeed(`${provider} plugin installed successfully!`)
      // execute npm install
    }
    checkSpinner.succeed(`${provider} module check complete`)
    return import(`${provider}-provider-plugin`)
  }
```